# Array Size Unhandled Exception (multi-dimensional)

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, background-subtraction

I need to create a Temporal Median Filter(Background subtraction) for a school project(Basically, choosing the pixels that appear most in the dataset to be the background). I'm getting a "Array size unhandled exception error". Also, i don't know if i am doing this correctly or not. I'm quite new and bad in programming. Thanks :)

```
int main() {

string img = "ts_04-11-21_16-27-00-mod";
Mat src = imread(img + ".jpg");

//nPixels = src.total();
int const nPixels = 76800;
int const nPhotos = 60;
int counter = 0;
int col = 0;
int row = 0;
int maxColumn = src.cols;
int myArray[nPixels][nPhotos];

//Storing Pixel values into arrays
for (int i = 0; i < nPixels; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < nPhotos; j++) {
        if (col == maxColumn - 1) {
            col = 0;
            row += 1;
        }
        myArray[i][j] = src.at<uint8_t>(row, col);
        counter += 1;
        string img = "ts_04-11-21_16-27-0" + to_string(counter) + "-mod";
        src = imread(img + ".jpg");
    }
    col++;
}

int desiredArray[nPhotos];
int finalArray[nPixels];
//Getting the median value amongst all photos
for (int i = 0; i < nPixels; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < nPhotos; j++) {
        desiredArray[j] = myArray[i][j];
    }
    int median = getMedian(desiredArray);
    finalArray[i] = median;
}

//Output the finalArray into the final picture
row = 0;
col = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < nPixels; i++) {
    src.at<uint8_t>(Point(row, col)) = finalArray[i];
    if (col == maxColumn - 1) {
        col = 0;
        row += 1;
    }

}

Mat medianPic = imread("ts_04-11-21_16-27-59-mod.jpg");
imshow("pic", medianPic);
system("pause");
return 0;
}

int getMedian(int myArray[]){
    int element = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(myArray); i++){
        int tempElement = myArray[i];
        int tempCount = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j <sizeof(myArray); j++) {
            if (myArray[j] == tempElement) 
                tempCount++;
            }
        if (tempCount > count) {
            element = tempElement;
            count = tempCount;
            }
        }
    return element;
    }
```

Essentially, what i am trying to do is to store the individual value of pixels from each picture and store them into an array, Apply median function on them, get the median pixel and output it.

Comment: Try `std::vector`, `76800 * 60` might be too big for automatic variable `myArray`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @SergeBallesta I might be blind, but where is the VLA? `const int` can be used as constant expressions.

Comment: @PasserBy: oups, I didn't pay attention to the `const` modifier. No VLA here...